# Let $f : \mathbb R → \mathbb R$ be deﬁned by $f(x) = |x|$.

Tags: general-topology

Prove or disprove:

> Let $f : \mathbb R → \mathbb R$ be deﬁned by $f(x) = |x|$. Then $f$ is $T_u − T_u$ continuous.

where $T_u$ is usual topology

Comment: Well you showed inverse image of interval is open interval. You need fact that any open set is union of intervals, but yea its basically right

Comment: @dr.rise, I have edited your post slightly. Please ensure that it still reflects the original intent, and if it does not, let me know and I will try and fix it.

Comment: (m,n) is not an element of R.  Why would you think it is?  Do you mean (m,n) subset R?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you are right, yet your answer is not complete though. It's an easy fact that a set in $\mathbb{R}$ is open if and only if it's the union of open intervals. So for any open set $U$, we have $$U=\cup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}V_{\lambda}.$$ where each $V_{\lambda}$ is an open interval. Thus,$$f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(\cup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}V_{\lambda})=\cup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}f^{-1}(V_{\lambda}).$$ As you have shown,each $f^{-1}(V_{\lambda})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, $f^{-1}(U)=\cup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}f^{-1}(V_{\lambda})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ for it's union of open sets, which implies $f$ is $T_{u}−T_{u}$ continuous.

Answer (score 1):

$\left|\,|x| - |y|\,\right| \le |x-y|$ by the reverse triangle inequality. So $f$ is Lipschitz, we can take $\delta = \epsilon$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. This gives us that $f$ is even uniformly continuous.

As for continuity via open sets: you indeed only have to check (by a simple lemma) $f^{-1}[O]$ is open for $O$ in a (sub)base for the topology, like open intervals, or open segments. But you either have to know / quote such a lemma, or prove it yourself (which is not hard).

Comment: @dr.rise What's the problem with  Y.Luo's answer? That is based on your definition.

Comment: @dr.rise you only checked it for open intervals, not arbitrary open sets.

Comment: And you assume $m,n >0$ as well. So not even *all* intervals.

Comment: Your formula is only valid in that case. You need to consider all cases.

Comment: Of course. You have to prove the claim it works for all intervals.

Comment: Think, maybe ?  You're almost there.